# unable to import ChatOpenAI in vscode because .chat_models is unavailable

Tags: openai-api, langchain

Ive imported langchain and openai in vscode but the .chat_models for langchain is not availabile

I pip installed langchain and openai and expected to be able to import ChatOpenAI from the langchain.chat_models but I am unble to find .chat_models

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons, you may be using, the lower version of langchain. So you may solve by

```
pip install --upgrade langchain
```

Then you may use

```
 from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
```

Answer (score 0):

I first ran
`pip install 'langchain[all]'` and ran into the same issue. Running `pip install -U langchain` resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Langchain package and its components might be incompatible with the Python version you are currently using.

**Check Python Version:** You can do this by running the following code snippet:

```py
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

Ensure that the displayed version aligns with your expectations (in this case, Python 3.11 at the time of writing). To confirm the most recent Python version, you can cross-reference the [official website](https://www.python.org/).