# unable to import ChatOpenAI in VScode

Tags: langchain

I am using Langchain 0.0.284 & 0.0.28 Open AI, I installed using PIP with Python 3.9 , also using when i am trying to run exmp0.py with following code, i am getting an error `module not found`, i did follow the link here [langchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344164/unable-to-import-chatopenai-in-vscode-because-chat-models-is-unavailable) but no use, earlier it was working smooth before i upgraded

Also am not sure if i need to use jupyter notebook. please advise.

`from langchain.llms import OpenAI`
`from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI`

`llm = OpenAI()`
`chat_model = ChatOpenAI()`

`llm.predict("hi!")`

I did follow the link here [langchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344164/unable-to-import-chatopenai-in-vscode-because-chat-models-is-unavailable) but no use, earlier it was working smooth before i upgraded ,

Comment: are you using conda ?

Comment: did you pip install ```langchain``` and ```openai``` ?

Comment: No @ZKS I was intrigued to use conda, but then considering  langchain complexity i installed with pip, but  then used conda to activate my  environment ,

Answer (score 1):

Below are steps if you are using anaconda

```
cd "you dir where you want to create venv"

"you dir">conda create --prefix ./your_env_name python=3.9 (you can change it based on you requirement)

 pip install langchain==0.0.284
```

You should now able to run the below code

```
  from langchain.llms import OpenAI
  from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

  llm = OpenAI()
  chat_model = ChatOpenAI()

  llm.predict("hi!")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to point to the right kernel, when i set it up it started working

Comment: random question did it change to llm.predict with the implementation of from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI? I use to write from langchain import OpenAI and llm(prompt) use to work just fine. Added the .predict and my issue was fixed tho, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ZKS, In case someone wants to use Python,

```
`pyhton3.9 -m venv virtual_environment`
```

& then activate  `source /virtual_environment/bin/activate`